# Javascript: Grab an array and sum all values

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, users can add timecode in and out points for their project, and the project automatically figures out the total duration of the timecode. But I want to add a function that will take all the available timecode durations, convert them to seconds, add them together, then convert the final number back to timecode and put it in a text input.

This is my code, but I keep getting syntax errors:

```
     function timeToSeconds(t) {
        var tc = t.split(':');
        return parseInt(tc[0])*3600 + parseInt(tc[1])*60 + parseInt(tc[2]);
    }

    function tcDuration(tcin, tcout) {
        function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
        var duration = timeToSeconds(tcout) - timeToSeconds(tcin);
        var hoursmins = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        return z(Math.floor(hoursmins/60)) + ':' + z(hoursmins % 60) + ':' + z(duration % 60);
    }

    // Run this function every time a film_tc_out cell is changed
    function film_tc_Duration() {
        if (document.getElementById("film_tc_in").value == '') {var film_tc_in = '00:00:00';} else { var film_tc_in = document.getElementById("film_tc_in").value;}
        if (document.getElementById("film_tc_out").value == '') {var film_tc_out = '00:00:00';} else { var film_tc_out = document.getElementById("film_tc_out").value;}
        document.getElementById("film_tc_duration").value = tcDuration(film_tc_in, film_tc_out);
    }

    // Run this function every time a src_tc_out cell is changed
    function src_tc_Duration() {
        if (document.getElementById("src_tc_in").value == '') {var src_tc_in = '00:00:00';} else { var src_tc_in = document.getElementById("src_tc_in").value;}
        if (document.getElementById("src_tc_out").value == '') {var src_tc_out = '00:00:00';} else { var src_tc_out = document.getElementById("src_tc_out").value;}
        document.getElementById("src_tc_duration").value = tcDuration(src_tc_in, src_tc_out);
    }

    // Run this function every time a src_wd_out cell is changed
    function src_wd_Duration() {
        if (document.getElementById("src_wd_in").value == '') {var src_wd_in = '00:00:00';} else { var src_wd_in = document.getElementById("src_wd_in").value;}
        if (document.getElementById("src_wd_out").value == '') {var src_wd_out = '00:00:00';} else { var src_wd_out = document.getElementById("src_wd_out").value;}
        document.getElementById("src_wd_duration").value = tcDuration(src_wd_in, src_wd_out);
    }

    function total_tc_Duration() {
    var val = document.getElementsByClassName('.asset_src_tc_duration');
    var total_tc = 0;
    var v;
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        v = timeToSeconds(val[i]); 
        if (!isNaN(v)) total_tc += v;
    }
    return (total_tc);
    }

function updateAssetTimecode() {
    document.getElementById("timecode_total").value = total_tc_Duration();
}
```

Update: I've rewritten the For Loop to see if that helps - it currently gives me an answer now, although the answer is always "0". It's not spitting out any errors but it seems to think the variable val isn't a number?

Comment: Are there more js or is this it?

Comment: There's a few solid errors I can see, but I have to ask - wouldn't it just be easier to work with `Date` objects?

Comment: I added all of the javascript in the file just in case there was an error elsewhere. @Greg - I used a similar function to convert time to minutes for a timesheet I made and figured coding it to convert to seconds and add would give me the best understanding of how javascript handles its functions

Comment: `right now it says that I'm missing a ) after argument list `: Then I'd suggest you track down the missing `)`. The *functions are undefined* errors are all cascading from that error. Use a decent editor that will highlight the matching brackets for you and it should help you find it.

Comment: your each() calls expect a function. you know, one that uses the word "function"...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the example I looked up online had function() and I thought that meant to replace it with the function I wanted to use there. I've updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your tcDuration function won't work like you expect.  You don't subtract the already calculated hours before doing the minutes calculation and the same with seconds.

```
function tcDuration(tcin, tcout) {
    function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
    var duration = timeToSeconds(tcout) - timeToSeconds(tcin);
    var hoursmins = Math.floor(duration / 60);
    return z(Math.floor(hoursmins / 60)) + ":" + z(hoursmins % 60) + ":" + z(duration % 60);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, it was working ok with really small numbers so I figured it was fine but hadn't tested it with larger values.